# Show files in browser in PHP

Tags: php, mime-types, content-type

I've made an upload mechanism and now I want to create a page that lets you view the files you uploaded. I want to show them in the browser however (I only have browser-supported files like images, PDF etc).

My guess is that I can do this by only setting some headers and printing the bytes of the file. But as far as I know, I need to set the `Content-type` header to display the content correctly. How can I get the content-type of a file? Is it the same as the mime-type?

Comment: Displaying a folder structure has nothing to do with content-types. You need to use the PHP file and folder functions.

Comment: So you want to use PHP to serve those files? Why not just link to them directly?

Comment: @powerbuoy cause if I would link to them, the browser would download them, not display them. @ Fluffeh, I don't want to show the folders, but the files in the browser. Just like you would use Chrome to view a file.

Comment: Hmm, my browser wouldn't do that. At least not if the files are "browser-supported files like images, PDF etc".

Comment: Hmmm apparently you're right, I've tried it and it doesn't download it. But I'll use the PHP script, because I don't want to disclose the location of my files on the hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its MIME type. Find a list at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type

Comment: Thanks, was the only answer that answered my actual question :)

Answer (score 2):

So as to process many different file types in browser itself you can use take help of [MIME Content-type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) which is deprecated  .

Or you can also use [finfo-file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) which also return s information about file.

Comment: Thanks, I knew how to get the MIME type, but didn't know if MIME type = Content-Type, so I guess I'll use one of the 2 you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read the contents of the file, print the appropriate headers and echo the contents. If the browser detects that it can display these file types it will display them else it will prompt the user to the save to the local system. The code will be something similar to the snippet specified below:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('file1.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have made for this problem is to use Apache's Indexing and applying some styles with `FancyIndexing`, check out [Apache Indexing Options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions), and you can display what MIME's you want to.

in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing 
        IndexOptions VersionSort 
        IndexOptions HTMLTable 
        IndexOptions FoldersFirst 
        IndexOptions IconsAreLinks 
        IndexOptions IgnoreCase 
        IndexOptions SuppressDescription 
        IndexOptions SuppressHTMLPreamble 
        IndexOptions XHTML 
        IndexOptions IconWidth=16 
        IndexOptions IconHeight=16 
        IndexOptions NameWidth=*
        IndexOrderDefault Descending Name
        HeaderName /style/header.php
        ReadmeName /style/footer.php
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['myupload']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['myupload']['type'];

header("Content-Type: ".$type);
echo $file;
```

It might not fully work, but it's a starting place.